# Verification of conclusions regarding duality maps

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I have two conclusions drawn from two results. I want to know how valid these two conclusions are. Firstly

Consider the duality mapping(set-valued) $J:X \rightrightarrows X^{*}$ defined: $J(u) := \{ f \in X^{*}: \langle f,u \rangle = \Vert u \Vert^{2} = \Vert f \Vert^{2} \}$.
We have the following property of the duality mapping:
If we take $X$ to be a separable Banach space then if $X^{*}$ is strictly convex then $J$ is single-valued.

Consider also the following corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Corollary:
If $X$ is normed space.
For all $x_{o} \in X$ there exists $f_{o} \in X^{*}$ such that $f_{0}(x_{o}) = \Vert x_{o}\Vert_{X}^{2}$ and $\Vert f_{o} \Vert_{X^{*}} = \Vert x_{o} \Vert_{X}$.

Now for the two conclusion consider $X$ as a separable, reflexive Banach space. If $X_{m} \subset X$ are finite-dimensional subspaces of dimension $m$ then I have the following two conclusions:

1. From the Corollary(noting that the $f_{o}$ mentioned is unique if $X^{*}$ is strictly convex or if $X$ is a Hilbert space) and Riesz-representation Theorem we can see that when in a Hilbert space the duality mapping $J$ is a single-valued surjective isometry(therefore also a homeomorphism) and we can therefore identify $X$ and $X^{*}$.
2. We note that the duality mapping $J_{m}$ is a surjective isometry follows from the Corollary and the additional properties the mapping has when on a strictly convex space(in this case a Hilbert space.) $X_{m}$ and $X_{m}^{*}$ are finite-dimensional and are therefore not only isomorphic to each other but are also isomorphic to a Euclidean space of finite-dimension. We can therefore consider $X_{m}$ and $X_{m}^{*}$ as being equivalent to the Euclidean space of some finite-dimension with the usual norm. We note that the Euclidean space with the usual norm is a Hilbert space. In a Hilbert space the duality mapping is again a surjective isomtry. We can therefore identify $X_{m}$ and $X_{m}^{*}$, and we of course have $\Vert J_{m}x \Vert_{X^{*}_{m}} = \Vert x \Vert_{X_{m}}$.

Are these conclusions fine? Are there any recommendation? Are there any redundant statements or statements that are simply incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious missing piece is: what do you mean by saying  **we can identify** two spaces? The natural interpretation is that "we can think of them as being the same space". But that's not very precise. A more precise form is: we know a  *canonical isometric isomorphism* between these space. This is how I understand the term, at least

To your first question. If $X$ is over real scalars, then $J$ is an isometric  isomorphism between $X$ and $X^*$: it is a bijective linear map that preserves the norm. So I'll say yes, we *can* identify them. (But there are cases when we *should not*, even though we *can*.)

If $X$ is over complex scalars, then $J$ is not a linear map: it is conjugate linear. One could say that $X^*$ can be identified with $\overline{X}$, a version of $X$ in which the scalar multiplication is defined differently, as $\alpha *x =  \bar\alpha x$.

To your second question: "being equivalent to the Euclidean space of some finite-dimension with the usual norm" introduces yet another undefined term, *being equivalent*. What does *that* mean?

Those spaces are  *isomorphic* in the sense that there is a linear bijection that is continuous both ways. But they are  not  *isometrically isomorphic* in general: being isometrically isomorphic requires a linear bijection that preserves the norm. People do not usually consider two isomorphic normed spaces as being "the same". Doing so would throw the entire theory  of the geometry of finite-dimensional normed spaces out of the window.

Comment: Thanks for your response, by "equivalent" I was referring to "isomorphic", but I agree that is not very well put. I have two questions. 1.What definition of "canonical" are you using, do you mean that it is canonical in that it does not depend on the basis of the vector spaces involved? 2. When you state "those spaces are isomorphic, but they are not isometrically isomorphic in general" what definition of isomorphic are you using? Are you stating that there is a linear bijection between them but not necessarily a linear bijective isometry?

Comment: @LucioD Yes, canonical means independent of any choices we make about the objects. In particular, independent of a choice of basis. I edited the last paragraph to explain item 2.

Comment: Oh okay so you define an isomorphism between two normed spaces as a linear homeomorphism? I thought that generally two normed spaces are stated as isomorphic if there exists a surjective isometry between them?

Comment: @LucioD So, when you wrote "$X_m$ and $X_m^*$ are finite-dimensional and are therefore not only isomorphic to each other but are also isomorphic to a Euclidean space of finite-dimension." you meant that between any two normed spaces of the same dimension there is a surjective isometry? That would be.... far from correct.

Comment: I don't think I meant that no but I have been getting different definitions from different sources, there doesn't seem to be a consensus. Even isometry is sometimes assumed to be linear and sometimes linear isometry is defined separately. So would I be right in stating the following isomorphisms for various algebraic structures: Sets- bijection, Vector Spaces - linear bijection, Topology- homeomorphism, Normed Vector Spaces- linear homeomorphism?

Comment: @LucioD There are no right or wrong definitions. The only question is whether it's consistent with the context in which it's used. Yes, those definitions  are consistent with much of the literature.

Comment: Would you form the isomorphism between $X_{m}$ and $X_{m}^{*}$ by considering the mapping $T(v_{i}) = u_{i}$ where $\{v_{i}\}$ is a basis for $X_{m}$ and $\{u_{i}\}$ is a basis for $X_{m}^{*}$ and then extending linearly or would you show that since they are both linearly homeomorphic to the euclidean space they must be linearly homeomorphic to each other?

Comment: @LucioD Either way, you are doing the same thing: taking a bijection between basis elements and extending it by linearity.

Comment: Oh okay I was asking since I was interested if a linear homeomorphism is transitive. I know a homeomorphism is.

Comment: @LucioD It is transitive. Composition of linear maps is linear.

Comment: Could you give me a hint or reference as to how to show that as you state if $X$ is over real scalars then $J$ is linear. When I stated that '$J$ was a surjective isometry' I was not assuming that it was also a linear surjective isometry.

Comment: I can see how $J$ is a surjective isometry using the Corollary and Riesz-representation as I stated but I can't see why it is guaranteed to be linear.